# How does *325# facebook application works

Tags: facebook

Dial *325# from your mobile phone. It will ask for facebook username/password. And will login to your account and will connect you to facebook through USSD. How do they do it? Is there any mechanism in any facebook api through which we can log in to user account, if he has provided us the username and password?

Comment: You mention a phone call but then login with sms.. I'm a little confused about what exactly you are asking...

Comment: @Lix I have edited my question. Basically when we dial *325# from phone, you are connected through USSD. IT asks for username,password and logs into facebook. And sends updates through sms.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly how the login via phone call works... But I can answer your question about the API:

The Facebook API does not provide a login method with username and password. All authentication though the API is done by means of tokens.

Comment: Thankyou for clearing my mind. It means they are doing some sort of web-scraping etc, I guess.

Comment: Well, if the login is being done directly with Facebook, they might have some other sort of authentication implemented, but yes - the only other way would be to forge a submit of a login form.

Comment: Not another cross-question, But I am wondering why facebook isn't taking some action against that app for taking username/password from users. The application doesn't have a small audience, it is being widely used all over the world especially in third world countries.

Comment: Maybe no one has reported it yet :P